# Why is there a torrc process running on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: configuration

I just noticed that there is a torrc process running on my Ubuntu machine.

I'm seeing this when I do a ps.

> debian-+  1260  0.3  0.7  76064 31384 ?        Ss   03:46   0:00
>   /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f
>   /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0

It starts at boot, and if I kill it it restarts. Is there a relay running on my machine? If so, how do I stop it? I can't spare the bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the torrc process - it's a tor process with command-line arguments too long to fit into one line, so it's split in two. The part "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0" is actually the command line arguments for tor process:

- *--defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc* sets the config file to read the defaults from. It says "not use built-in ones, read them from there"
- *-f /etc/tor/torrc* tells to read the settings from `/etc/tor/torrc` file
- *--RunAsDaemon 0* tells tor not to become a daemon process even if in defaults-torrc or torrc config it was told to do so. It's a command line level override

Comment: Okay. Looking at it again I can see that you're right. I'm not sure where my head was last night.  So why is there a tor process running?

Comment: how exactly has you installed Tor? from packages/repository? From sources?

Answer (score 2):

The tor process is automatically started by the system service manager by default.

It is not a relay by default, only a client, so you are not relaying other peoples traffic.

To temporarily stop the service issue the command `sudo service tor stop`.

To [disable the service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services):

- If you're running Ubuntu >= 15.04 issue the command: `sudo systemctl disable tor`
- If you're running an older version of Ubuntu issue the command: `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/tor.override`

When it's not running, to manually start the service issue the command `sudo service tor start`.